# Prevent using the same JSESSIONID in different browsers + Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am creating an application using grails 2.2.3 and spring security 1.2.7.3.
When I login, I copy the JSESSIONID and use it in another browser (I can access the data). How could I prevent using the same JSESSIONID in different browsers and logout the user?

Comment: How do you copy the session ID? By default it is a cookie that you can't copy that easy.

Comment: He is using spring security as pointed out by the tag he used. @JeffScottBrown